# Bash script or python script to unzip a file and give the files name of the current date from the extracted files?

Tags: bash

I need a bash script to get the file name of current date, For ex- 20171104.1

1. Unzip the latest file in a directory.
2. extract the name of the file which are generated on the current date from the list of extracted files.
3. Zip contains two files: 20171031.1 and 20171104.1.  I need only  20171104.1 to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: I am able to extract the files but its returning me appended ./ values with file name.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood you got a zip file **abc.zip** and you want to extract the latest file from it. If I am wrong please leave a comment and I will sort it out accordingly and if I am not wrong this script will work for you:

```
a="$(date -d $(date -I) +%Y%m%d)"
b="$(unzip -l abc.zip)"
c="$(echo "$b" | grep "$a")"

unzip -j abc.zip $c 2> /dev/null
```

In this script first of all we are getting current date formatting it into YYYYMMDD without dashes or slashes. Then we are listing out the contents in it and by regular expression we are matching the modified date of the file if it matches our current date it will throw the file for us. To just get the file name which is the last word of the string output we used *awk* and finally unzipping our desired file instead of all the files inside it.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat for your script but it is only displaying me the first file with date name. Suppose in my zip contains 20171029, 20171030.1 , 20171106.1 , 20171106.2 ,and 20171106.3 . Today date is 6 NOV , So when I run my script it returns me the values with file name like  20171106.1 , 20171106.2 ,and 20171106.3 but your script is only returning  20171106.1. Kindly help bro !!!!!

Comment: @PuneetKumar now its good to go as per your requirements. You can also look answer below but if you want step by step go for it. Any doubt you are welcome to ask in comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple one line**

```
unzip -j abc.zip $(unzip -l abc.zip | grep -o "$(date +%Y%m%d).*")
```

**Example output**

```
$ unzip -l abc.zip 
Archive:  abc.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-11-06 11:10   20171102.1
        0  2017-11-06 11:10   20171104.3
        0  2017-11-06 11:09   20171106.1
        0  2017-11-06 11:10   20171106.2
---------                     -------
        0                     4 files
$ unzip -j abc.zip $(unzip -l abc.zip | grep -o "$(date +%Y%m%d).*")
Archive:  abc.zip
 extracting: 20171106.1              
 extracting: 20171106.2              
$
```